# unshift and assigning an array is failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a object called response with an array of questions.

I have this code that fails

```
    self.qs = response.questions;
    self.qs.unshift(null);
```

and this code works:

```
    self.qs = angular.copy(response.questions);
    self.qs.unshift(null);
```

Can someone explain what's going on.

Here's my console log:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(self.qs))
VM919:1 [{"answer":null,"answerGridCorrect":null,"answerGridResponses":null,"answered":false,"correctCount":0,"hint":null,"incorrectCount":0,"questionNumber":1,"questionUId":"511efb60-f909-4cd1-894f-e313f2c990b0","locked":false,"result":"N","shownCount":0,"tagged":false,"text":"How many legs do cats have?","userTestQuestionId":14546,"answerGrid":[{"answerId":4996,"text":"1","correct":null,"response":null},{"answerId":4997,"text":"4","correct":null,"response":null},{"answerId":4998,"text":"3","correct":null,"response":null},{"answerId":4999,"text":"2","correct":null,"response":null}]},{"answer":null,"answerGridCorrect":null,"answerGridResponses":null,"answered":false,"correctCount":0,"hint":null,"incorrectCount":0,"questionNumber":2,"questionUId":"458559e0-e4fe-4830-a276-ec3633b5bf64","locked":false,"result":"N","shownCount":0,"tagged":false,"text":"How many legs do dogs have?","userTestQuestionId":14547,"answerGrid":[{"answerId":4992,"text":"2","correct":null,"response":null},{"answerId":4993,"text":"4","correct":null,"response":null},{"answerId":4994,"text":"1","correct":null,"response":null},{"answerId":4995,"text":"3","correct":null,"response":null}]}]
undefined
self.qs.questions.unshift(null)
VM921:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined(…)
```

I'm very confused about this, I have a solution but I am not sure why it works.

Comment: Can you give more context? There must be something happening between the first and second lines that's not explained in the question.

Comment: The first code (`self.qs.unshift(null);`) doesn't match the console.log code (`self.qs.questions.unshift(null)`).

Comment: Could you please correct the question so that the code on the one hand, and the output in the console on the other hand are in separate blocks, and correspond? Right now it is confusing. like mentioned above. Also it is not clear why generated the `undefined` in the console. Please give consistent information.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code.

Your array of questions is `self.qs`. You should perform the `unshift()` on `self.qs`, and not on `self.qs.questions` (which is `undefined` - thus the error).

Using `angular.copy()` as you may know, returns a copy of the original array. Performing `unshift()` on the copy leaves the original array intact, which is generally a good practice.

Fixing the typo should solve your problem. `angular.copy()`, as you suspected, would not make a difference in this case.